# setInterval Doesn't Clear onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an HTML file with a form that I'm trying to autosave. In a separate file I have my save function. The issue I'm running into is `intervalID` doesn't clear when navigating away from the page. If I go to another page I still get logs to the console. Why doesn't `clearInterval` run before the page unloads?

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Manage saving
    var intervalID
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        intervalID = setInterval(function(){save('stateBioEditor', '0', 'bioInfo')}, 120000);
    });

    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        //goodbye
        save('stateBioEditor', '0', 'bioInfo');
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        return undefined;
    };
</script>

<form id="bioInfo" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <!--Inputs-->
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function save(type, id, form) {
    console.log('saving');
    var tempData = $("form#" + form).serialize();
    console.log(tempData);
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: tempData,
        url: 'file.php?type=' + type + '&recID=' + id,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You're calling `save()` in `onbeforeunload`, so you're getting `console.log` from there. Then, when the next page loads, you'll get the logging from the initial call of `save()` from `setInterval()`... What actually is the issue here?

Comment: *"Why doesn't clearInterval run before the page unloads?"* It does. But even if it didn't, it wouldn't matter, because unloading the page clears the interval timer anyway.